# Is maximizing $x^H A^{-1} x$ equivalent to minimizing $x^H A x$ for symmetric positive definite A?

Tags: equivalence-relations, quadratic-forms, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

Is maximizing $x^H A^{-1} x$ in terms of $x$ equivalent to minimizing $x^H A x$ for symmetric positive definite $A$?

$x$ is variable of $N \times 1$ vector and $A$ is given square matrix of size $N \times N$. The vector $x$ must be constrained to have norm $||x||^2_2=1$ to prevent maximizing to be infinity.

Maybe $A$ could be decomposed into $PDP^{-1}$, so that $A^{-1} = PD^{-1}P^{-1}$, and it could be relevant to solving the proposition.
Please answer me..

Comment: No, if $A \neq 0$ then the $\max$ is $\infty$ and the $\min$ is zero. Are you sure this is what you were trying to ask?

Comment: Take $A=I$, then there is no finite upper bound and the $\min$ is zero. What are you expecting?

Comment: However, I wonder if $x$ is only constrained to be $||x||^2=1$, to be general

Comment: Decide what you want to ask and ask it.

Comment: I mean maximizing $x^H A^{−1} x$ in terms of x, not $A$. A is determined one.

Comment: I really don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: I edited my question to prevent confusion.

Comment: What would be the answer if $A$ was diagonal?

Comment: If A is diagonal as $diag[\lambda_1, \lambda_2, ..., \lambda_N]$ the inverse matrix should be $diag[\frac{1}{\lambda_1}, \frac{1}{\lambda_2}, ..., \frac{1}{\lambda_N}]$. Therefore, I guess the statement should be correct